# Theory about VLF?

Tags: radio, signal

Trying to make my own vlf receiver, but couldn't find a good literature about it.

- Does anybody know any good books about VLF theory?
- And also, link to working circuits?

All stuff I have found out was published in late 90-s.

Comment: [This VLF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_low_frequency)?

Comment: yes, very low frequency

Comment: can you give us more details about what you are trying to do? A transformer is a pretty standard example of a VLF transmitter and receiver. If you are going long range, as this discusses, they use antennas on the orders of miles long.

Comment: I want to make compact vlf receiver, for know I have simple schematics and huge antenna. I want to connect my device to android tablet and use software instead of building complex receiver,to switch between frequencies and see signal visualization.That's why I want to improve my theoretical background in vlf.

Comment: "VLF" is no spec at all.  What frequency range do you want to receive?

Comment: is there something wrong with the literature you found? being 10-20 years old isn't going to matter a whole lot for low frequency receivers.

Comment: I have 2 books.Books are from 60's, schematics from late 90's. I was wondering that there was some developments in this field, since it used for naval communication with submarines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the book **[LF Today](http://www.arrl.org/shop/LF-Today/)** by Mike Dennison, G3XDV and Jim Moritz, M0BMU?

> LF Today is based on the experience of leading LF experimenters and
>   provides readers with a firm knowledge of the low frequency bands. It
>   includes practical information on antennas, transmitters, receivers
>   and propagation specific to LF operation. This edition has been
>   expanded to include updates that reflect the experimental work on the
>   136 kHz band, including gaining a greater understanding of low
>   frequency sky-wave propagation. There are also details on the special
>   research done using low power just above 500 kHz.
>
> This book is a great resource for everyone interested in low frequency
>   amateur radio. There is advice and techniques for amateurs just
>   starting out, and useful reference information for those with a more
>   technical background or who already have some experience in LF.
>
> 160 pages. Second edition. © 2007, published by Radio Society of Great
>   Britain (RSGB).

At the present time there is increasing interest in LF by radio amateurs, particulary in light of [Agenda Item 1.23](http://www.arrl.org/news/agenda-item-1-23-passes-committee-moves-to-plenary) (worldwide secondary allocation to the Amateur Service at 472-479 kHz)  at the [WRC](http://www.itu.int/ITU-R/index.asp?category=conferences&rlink=wrc&lang=en) (It is the job of WRC to review, and, if necessary, revise the Radio Regulations, the international treaty governing the use of the radio-frequency spectrum)